# Counting differences among duplicates

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table:

| id | Name | School |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | middle |
| 458 | Katherine | high |
| 001 | Johnson | middle |
| 380 | Macy | elementary |
| 458 | Lucy | high |
| 293 | Nancy | high |
| 541 | Luke | elementary |
| 001 | Johnson | high |

Of the rows that have duplicate IDs, I want a count of how many of them have different names. So my end result is:

| id | count | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2 | 1 |
| 458 | 1 | 1 |

(001 would be 2 for Johnson and 1 for John. and then 458 would be 1 for Katherine and 1 for Lucy)

I have the query to find duplicate ids `select id from Students group by id having count(id)>1`

and have tried `select id, name, count(id), count(name) from Students group by id, name having count(id)>1 and count(name)>1`

but this returns

| id | name | count(id) | count(name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Johnson | 2 | 2 |

Comment: I do not know databricks, but In MySQL you can do: https://dbfiddle.uk/VX7mShXZ

Comment: I believe you would want something like: `SELECT id, count(distinct Name), count(distinct School) FROM Students GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1`